# What is a Rum Cutter?

Tags: vocabulary

I would be very grateful if someone in the community could provide me with a definition of a rum cutter. The term appears in Thomas Frederick Littler's diary entry on June, 7th 1916.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> [June 7th 1916](https://www.firstworldwar.com/diaries/littlerdiary3.htm)
>
> We left our billets and went to the edge of the village, moving 
>   undercover of the broken walls, then entered a communication trench
>   called 'Yale Street' (of y sector y29) moved along this trench in
>   daylight for 300yds and then we were only 100yds from our own front
>   line, and 400yds from the enemy front line, this 'com' trench was in
>   places only 3ft deep, and we were exposed to the enemy fire, and our
>   own work was to deepen this trench to 7ft, also make it wide enough
>   for two men to pass, no earth could be thrown on top, but had to be
>   put in sandbags and passed down the trench.
>
> Everything went well 'till 3o'clock in the afternoon when 'Jerry' 
>   started to strafe, and strafed us away from the work, and managed it
>   without any casualties, during the time we were working we had to keep
>   our equipment on, also rifles at hand, and leaving the trench we
>   looked **'rum cutters'** being covered with mud and clay, all around the
>   place were 'gas alarms'. This day was the first time I had been close
>   to the enemy lines, and the first time I had got as far as a Support
>   trench.

Comment: Context would also help.  A "cutter" may be a knife, or it may be a boat.  In cricket it is a fastball.  In N. America it is a horse-drawn sleigh.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without more context: please provide the actual wording in the diary, and any relevant details that might help explain it. For example, to "cut" something can mean to water it down, so perhaps Mr Littler believes his publican is shortchanging him. Alternatively, a cutter is a kind of boat, and "rum" can mean odd or peculiar, so perhaps he means a weird boat...

Comment: I suspect that it refers to a cutter (type of sailboat) used for transporting rum (the drink).  But we really need some context!

Comment: (Given the context, my suspicion was wrong.)

Comment: I think it was a boat used to intercept the rum-runners. Even before Prohibition there were states where alcohol was banned. And before that the Brits were using "revenue-cutters" to stop pirates smuggling rum to the colonies. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rum-running

Comment: @Hot Licks Yeah. The context would've saved me an hour or so!

Comment: "Rum" is slightly old-fashioned BrE slang for "odd" or "peculiar".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiring_party: "Wiring parties, (or wiring sappers, cutters), were used during World War I on the Western Front as an offensive countermeasure against the enemy’s barbed wire obstacles."

Comment: Yes. I think I've got it now. Should I make it an answer?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Yes, please do.

Comment: I have no proof of this, hence it's a comment and not an answer, but I think the most likely meaning of a "rum cutter" was someone who "cut a rum figure". In other words someone presenting an odd or eccentric image. The word "rum" meaning "odd" is almost extinct now but "cutting a figure" and, in particular "cuttng a dash" is still used in some circles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems from his diaries that Littler was doing the work of a sapper throughout the war: preparing field defenses, building bridges, making roads and clearing barbed wire. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiring_party), "Wiring parties, (or wiring sappers, ***cutters***), were used during World War I on the Western Front as an offensive countermeasure against the enemy’s barbed wire obstacles." . . . "Work was done at night to repair, improve, and rebuild their own wire defences, while also sabotaging and cutting the enemy's." That is exactly what Littler was doing. I think the word *cutters*, for *wiring sappers*, is a slang term which has completely fallen from use during the last hundred years.

The adjective [*rum*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/rum) is BrE slang for *odd* or *peculiar*. It's a rather old-fashioned word now, but Littler would probably have heard it when he was growing up and it would certainly have been used in the trenches.

So he is saying, "We looked like very odd sappers, all covered in mud." And he puts it in quotes - "rum cutters" - because both words are slang. Or rather, to show that he *knows* they're slang. He does the same thing a few lines before with 'Jerry', meaning 'the Germans' and 'com' meaning 'communications'.

Comment: Many thanks! Thanks to Hot Licks for amending my question, making it easier to understand. And Many thanks to Old Brixtonian for the wonderful answer!